# Clustering millions of large binary vectors?

Tags: python, vector, binary, hierarchical-clustering, vaex

I want to generate millions of large binary vectors (10_000 ... 100_000 bits).
Then I want to cluster them by OVERLAP (AND) .
After that I want to reorder the vectors according to the clustering and save it for later.

Scipy have a clustering method but probably it wont work on such a large dataset.
Numpy wont work, cause i will get out of memory.
Vaex may work but i have to write the clustering algorithm myself and it will be in python, so it will be slow and read/only. Also I'm not sure what format to use when generating the data : csv,hdf5 ??

Any possible solution ? any other tool or technique ?

It is also an option to cluster them as i generate them, if that is possible ? I have to do some clever indexing technique !!!

Comment: "Probably won't work" - have you tried it? What was the problem?

Comment: not yet... i just started, thats why i asked the question what road to take .. and i listed some options i thought of